# Spring ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider handleBindException - Supplied password was invalid error

Tags: spring-security, active-directory, passwords, spring-ldap

We are trying to use Spring security for authenticating against our enterprise LDAP. I'm using `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`. Below is the snippet from the Spring config file:

```
<security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="true">
    <security:authentication-provider  ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
<constructor-arg value="DC=xxx,DC=ds,DC=yyy,DC=com" />  
<constructor-arg value="ldap://xxx.ds.yyy.com:389" />
<property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I'm getting: *ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider handleBindException Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid error.*

My understanding is that, this is because LDAP bind is failing as it is looking for userDN/credentials. How do we specify this information in the configuration file?

Prior to using `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`, I had got this working using `<ldap-authentication-provider>` and `DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource`. I was able to specify the userDN/password while configuring the `DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource` bean. Can someone tell me how to specify the userDn and password while configuring using `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you might be a bit confused about what `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` does and [how to configure it](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e6795). It binds using an email-like name in the form `user@domain.com` where `domain.com` is the argument you've supplied in the first constructor. It doesn't use a standard LDAP DN. This is specific to Active Directory and not part of standard LDAP.
You might also want to take a look at [the source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java) and Javadoc for the class.

If you already had a standard LDAP authentication configuration working with your setup, then it's not clear why you would want to change. You're probably better sticking with what you have as it won't be directly compatible with `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the urls Luke!! All of this makes sense now. For some reason I kind of thought using ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider was the right way to implement. Looks like I was wrong.