# Spring MVC application authenticating to Active Directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, active-directory

I realize that this question has been asked already, but I haven't found a solution in any other post that matches my situation.

I am writing a Spring MVC java application, and I am trying to get it to authenticate against our Active Directory system. I am using Spring Tools Suite 3.4.0 and have created a Spring MVC project. I am using Spring Security 3.1.1, and once completed, this application will be deployed to a Tomcat 7 java server running on Linux.

I have a user in our Active Directory system whose password I know is valid since I have other applications that authenticate against this same Active Directory system, and I can successfully authenticate with this user in the other applications. The userid is:

myuser@mycompany.com

You can see that the userids stored in our Active Directory system are in the format of email address.

The Domain Controller in our Active Directory system is: addomain.mycompany.com. Underneath the Domain Controller is an OU called ExternalUsers, and this OU has two sub OUs called Groups and Users. So the path to my user would be:

CN=myuser@mycompany.com,OU=Users,OU=ExternalUsers,DC=addomain,DC=mycompany,DC=com

The intercept works just fine...whenever I try navigating to any url in the application, I get redirected to the login page. The trouble that I'm having is with authentication. When I put in my userid and password and click Submit, the authentication fails. This is what I'm seeing in the logs:

```
2014-05-12 08:42:32,916 DEBUG: org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider - Processing authentication request for user: myuser@mycompany.com
2014-05-12 08:42:33,383 DEBUG: org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider - Authentication for myuser@mycompany.com@addomain failed:
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]
2014-05-12 08:42:33,384 INFO : org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider - Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid
```

I have listed the relevant files in my project below.

In the spring-security-context.xml file, I have tried changing this line:

```
<beans:constructor-arg value="addomain" />
```

to this:

```
<beans:constructor-arg value="addomain.mycompany.com" />
```

Unfortunately, I am seeing the same behavior. The logs are the same as above.

I have also tried switching the following line in spring-security-context.xml from this:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

to this:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

But unfortunately I get the same results. Do I need to create an Active Directory group whose name matches the role name (ie, ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_USER)?

I found another post that seems to match the issue that I'm having:

[Spring ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider handleBindException - Supplied password was invalid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069390/spring-activedirectoryldapauthenticationprovider-handlebindexception-supplied)

Unfortunately it didn't really provide a solution.

Something that I discovered is that the Active Directory users that I have been working with had sAMAccountName values that did not match the userid. I created a new user whose sAMAccountName matched
the userid, and suddenly I got past the "Supplied password was invalid" message. However, now I'm getting the following message when trying to log in:

org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

The full stack trace is:

```
2014-05-12 13:34:53,488 DEBUG: org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider - Processing authentication request for user: myuser@mycompany.com
2014-05-12 13:34:53,578 INFO : org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Ignoring PartialResultException
May 12, 2014 1:34:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/pima] threw exception
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:239)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.searchForUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:258)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:61)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:194)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I'm kind of stuck at this point can anyone help me understand what it is that I'm doing wrong here and/or what do I need to do to get this to work?

Here's my login.jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="loginForm" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' >    </c:url>" >
     <table>
<tr>
            <td>
            UserId:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="50" name="j_username"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Password:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" name="j_password"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />

<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here's my servlet-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.pima" />

<!-- Create DataSource Bean for connection to the SQL Server database -->
<beans:bean id="dbDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="adSettings"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/adSettings"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="portalSettings"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/portalSettings"/>
</beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Here's my root-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

<import resource="spring-security-context.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Here's my spring-security-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http pattern="/login" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/logerror" security="none" />

<!-- LDAP server details -->
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" class="com.mycompany.pima.security.ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper"/>

<beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="addomain" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://dev_ad_system.addomain.mycompany.com:389/" />
    <beans:property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" />
    <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<security:http auto-config="true" pattern="/**">
    <!-- Login pages -->
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/users"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login"/>

       <!-- Security zones -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

</security:http>

</beans:beans>
```

And lastly, here's my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>pima</artifactId>
<name>PIMA</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Thank you,

-Stephen Spalding

Comment: Can you try taking a known user/password and logging into AD directly using the tool of your choosing?  The 49/52e error is a user credentials error, which I believe means it doesn't think you have the correct username/password combo.  Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html

Comment: Hello! Yes, I've got another application that I can use to test authentication, and it works for the user that I'm testing with. Again, after creating a user with sAMAccountName and userid matching each other, I got past the javax.naming.AuthenticationException and am now stuck on the error org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update...I believe that I have solved my problem.

First, the original issue that I was dealing with was where I was receiving the message below when trying to log in with a known good userid/password:

```
org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider - Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid
```

I can confirm that this issue was resolved once I created a new user whose userid and sAMAccountName values in Active Directory were the same. The authentication piece
did not work until I did this and started testing with that user.

The second issue that I dealt with was after I started using the user with matching userid and sAMAccountNames. I started receiving the following message when trying to log in:

```
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
```

I ended up implementing my own custom authentication provider and had to make some tweaks to it to get it to work with our Active Directory system. I have posted each of the class 
files that I created below.

Lastly, there must exist an Active Directory group that matches the constant's value in the ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper class, and your user must be included in this group.
See this line in that file:

```
private String ROLE_ADMIN = "ExtranetUsers";
```

There's probably more issues to solve that I haven't encountered yet, but I can say that I am now successfully logging to my Spring application via Active Directory.

I put all of the class files that I created for my custom authentication provider in a package called com.mycompany.pima.security. Please note that implementing this custom 
authentication provider is what I did in addition to the configurations in login.jsp, web.xml, servlet-context.xml, root-context.xml, spring-security-context.xml and pom.xml.
The files in the the com.mycompany.pima.security package are:

ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java: (see my comments in the searchForUser() method for what I did that finally worked)

```
package com.mycompany.pima.security;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.DefaultDirObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountExpiredException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate;
import     org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider {
private static final Pattern SUB_ERROR_CODE = Pattern.compile(".*data\\s([0-9a-f]{3,4}).*");

// Error codes
private static final int USERNAME_NOT_FOUND = 0x525;
private static final int INVALID_PASSWORD = 0x52e;
private static final int NOT_PERMITTED = 0x530;
private static final int PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 0x532;
private static final int ACCOUNT_DISABLED = 0x533;
private static final int ACCOUNT_EXPIRED = 0x701;
private static final int PASSWORD_NEEDS_RESET = 0x773;
private static final int ACCOUNT_LOCKED = 0x775;

private final String domain;
private final String rootDn;
private final String url;
private boolean convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.class);

// Only used to allow tests to substitute a mock LdapContext
ContextFactory contextFactory = new ContextFactory();

/**
 * @param domain the domain for which authentication should take place
 */
//    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(String domain) {
//        this (domain, null);
//    }

/**
 * @param domain the domain name (may be null or empty)
 * @param url an LDAP url (or multiple URLs)
 */
public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(String domain, String url) {

    Assert.isTrue(StringUtils.hasText(url), "Url cannot be empty");
    this.domain = StringUtils.hasText(domain) ? domain.toLowerCase() : null;
    //this.url = StringUtils.hasText(url) ? url : null;
    this.url = url;
    rootDn = this.domain == null ? null : rootDnFromDomain(this.domain);
}

@Override
protected DirContextOperations doAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth) {

    String username = auth.getName();
    String password = (String)auth.getCredentials();
    DirContext ctx = bindAsUser(username, password);

    try {
        return searchForUser(ctx, username);

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to locate directory entry for authenticated user: " + username, e);
        throw badCredentials(e);
    } finally {
        LdapUtils.closeContext(ctx);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates the user authority list from the values of the {@code memberOf} attribute obtained from the user's
 * Active Directory entry.
 */
@Override
protected Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> loadUserAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username, String password) {
    String[] groups = userData.getStringAttributes("memberOf");

    if (groups == null) {
        logger.debug("No values for 'memberOf' attribute.");
        return AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES;
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("'memberOf' attribute values: " + Arrays.asList(groups));
    }

    ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(groups.length);

    for (String group : groups) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(new DistinguishedName(group).removeLast().getValue()));
    }

    return authorities;
}

private DirContext bindAsUser(String username, String password) {
    // TODO. add DNS lookup based on domain
    final String bindUrl = url;

    Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

    String bindPrincipal = createBindPrincipal(username);

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, bindPrincipal);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, bindUrl);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.OBJECT_FACTORIES, DefaultDirObjectFactory.class.getName());

    try {
        return contextFactory.createContext(env);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        if ((e instanceof AuthenticationException) || (e instanceof OperationNotSupportedException)) {
            handleBindException(bindPrincipal, e);
            throw badCredentials(e);
        } else {
            throw LdapUtils.convertLdapException(e);
        }
    }
}

void handleBindException(String bindPrincipal, NamingException exception) {

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Authentication for " + bindPrincipal + " failed:" + exception);
    }

    int subErrorCode = parseSubErrorCode(exception.getMessage());

    if (subErrorCode > 0) {
        logger.info("Active Directory authentication failed: " + subCodeToLogMessage(subErrorCode));

        if (convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions) {
            raiseExceptionForErrorCode(subErrorCode, exception);
        }
    } else {
        logger.debug("Failed to locate AD-specific sub-error code in message");
    }
}

int parseSubErrorCode(String message) {
    Matcher m = SUB_ERROR_CODE.matcher(message);

    if (m.matches()) {
        return Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16);
    }

    return -1;
}

void raiseExceptionForErrorCode(int code, NamingException exception) {

    String hexString = Integer.toHexString(code);
    Throwable cause = new ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException(hexString, exception.getMessage(), exception);
    switch (code) {
        case PASSWORD_EXPIRED:
            throw new CredentialsExpiredException(messages.getMessage("LdapAuthenticationProvider.credentialsExpired",
                    "User credentials have expired"), cause);
        case ACCOUNT_DISABLED:
            throw new DisabledException(messages.getMessage("LdapAuthenticationProvider.disabled",
                    "User is disabled"), cause);
        case ACCOUNT_EXPIRED:
            throw new AccountExpiredException(messages.getMessage("LdapAuthenticationProvider.expired",
                    "User account has expired"), cause);
        case ACCOUNT_LOCKED:
            throw new LockedException(messages.getMessage("LdapAuthenticationProvider.locked",
                    "User account is locked"), cause);
        default:
            throw badCredentials(cause);
    }
}

String subCodeToLogMessage(int code) {
    switch (code) {
        case USERNAME_NOT_FOUND:
            return "User was not found in directory";
        case INVALID_PASSWORD:
            return "Supplied password was invalid";
        case NOT_PERMITTED:
            return "User not permitted to logon at this time";
        case PASSWORD_EXPIRED:
            return "Password has expired";
        case ACCOUNT_DISABLED:
            return "Account is disabled";
        case ACCOUNT_EXPIRED:
            return "Account expired";
        case PASSWORD_NEEDS_RESET:
            return "User must reset password";
        case ACCOUNT_LOCKED:
            return "Account locked";
    }

    return "Unknown (error code " + Integer.toHexString(code) +")";
}

private BadCredentialsException badCredentials() {
    return new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                    "LdapAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
}

private BadCredentialsException badCredentials(Throwable cause) {
    return (BadCredentialsException) badCredentials().initCause(cause);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private DirContextOperations searchForUser(DirContext ctx, String username) throws NamingException {
    SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    // This was the original setting for searchFilter:
    // String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))";

    // These are some of the values that I played around with:
    // String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(userPrincipalName={0})(sAMAccountName={1})))";
    // String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)((sAMAccountName={1})))";
    // String searchFilter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + username + "))";

    // This is the final searchFilter value that I used that actually worked:
    String searchFilter = "(&(cn=" + username + "))";

    final String bindPrincipal = createBindPrincipal(username);

    String searchRoot = rootDn != null ? rootDn : searchRootFromPrincipal(bindPrincipal);
    // This is also something that I had to add to match my OU path:
    searchRoot = "ou=ExternalUsers," + searchRoot;

    try {
        return SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(ctx, searchCtls, searchRoot, searchFilter,
            new Object[]{bindPrincipal});
    } catch (IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException incorrectResults) {
        if (incorrectResults.getActualSize() == 0) {
            UsernameNotFoundException userNameNotFoundException = new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " not found in directory.", username);
            userNameNotFoundException.initCause(incorrectResults);
            throw badCredentials(userNameNotFoundException);
        }
        // Search should never return multiple results if properly configured, so just rethrow
        throw incorrectResults;
    }
}

private String searchRootFromPrincipal(String bindPrincipal) {
    int atChar = bindPrincipal.lastIndexOf('@');

    if (atChar < 0) {
        logger.debug("User principal '" + bindPrincipal + "' does not contain the domain, and no domain has been configured");
        throw badCredentials();
    }

    return rootDnFromDomain(bindPrincipal.substring(atChar+ 1, bindPrincipal.length()));
}

private String rootDnFromDomain(String domain) {
    String[] tokens = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(domain, ".");
    StringBuilder root = new StringBuilder();

    for (String token : tokens) {
        if (root.length() > 0) {
            root.append(',');
        }
        root.append("dc=").append(token);
    }

    return root.toString();
}

String createBindPrincipal(String username) {
    if (domain == null || username.toLowerCase().endsWith(domain)) {
        return username;
    }
    return username + "@" + domain;
}

/**
 * By default, a failed authentication (LDAP error 49) will result in a {@code BadCredentialsException}.
 * <p>
 * If this property is set to {@code true}, the exception message from a failed bind attempt will be parsed
 * for the AD-specific error code and a {@link CredentialsExpiredException}, {@link DisabledException},
 * {@link AccountExpiredException} or {@link LockedException} will be thrown for the corresponding codes. All
 * other codes will result in the default {@code BadCredentialsException}.
 *
 * @param convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions {@code true} to raise an exception based on the AD error code.
 */
public void setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(boolean convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions) {
    this.convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions = convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions;
}

static class ContextFactory {
    DirContext createContext(Hashtable<?,?> env) throws NamingException {
        return new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    }
}
}
```

ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper.java: (see my comment about the Active Directory group that must exist for the value given to ROLE_ADMIN. Also
ROLE_ADMIN ***MUST*** be referenced in the spring-security-context.xml file in the security:intercept-url tag)

```
package com.mycompany.pima.security;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.GrantedAuthoritiesMapper;

public class ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper implements GrantedAuthoritiesMapper {

// Constants for group defined in LDAP
// The string "ExtranetUsers" in the ROLE_ADMIN var below actually maps to the name
// of an Active Directory group.
private String ROLE_ADMIN = "ExtranetUsers";

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper.class);

public ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper() {

}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(
        final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

    Set<SecurityContextAuthority> roles = EnumSet.noneOf(SecurityContextAuthority.class);

    for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {

        // authority.getAuthority() returns the role in LDAP nomenclature
        if (ROLE_ADMIN.equals(authority.getAuthority())) {
            roles.add(SecurityContextAuthority.ROLE_ADMIN);
        }
    }
    return roles;
}
 }
```

ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException.java:

```
package com.mycompany.pima.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public final class ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException extends AuthenticationException {
private final String dataCode;

ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException(String dataCode, String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
    this.dataCode = dataCode;
}

public String getDataCode() {
    return dataCode;
}
}
```

SecurityContextAuthority.java:

```
package com.mycompany.pima.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

public enum SecurityContextAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

// These roles are specified in the security context (security.xml) and are
// mapped to LDAP roles by the ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper
ROLE_ADMIN;

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return name();
}   
}
```

Then I had to adjust my spring-security-context.xml file. Here is what it looks like now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http pattern="/login" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/logerror" security="none" />

<!-- LDAP server details -->
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" class="com.mycompany.pima.security.ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper"/>

<beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="addomain.mycompany.com" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://dev_ad_system.addomain.mycompany.com:389/" />
    <beans:property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" />
    <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<security:http auto-config="true" pattern="/**">
    <!-- Login pages -->
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/users"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login"/>

       <!-- Security zones -->
       <!-- ROLE_ADMIN mentioned in the line below must match the name of the constant in the ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper.java file. -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

</security:http>

</beans:beans>
```

I hope this helps someone, as I know how complicated and frustrating this can be.

Thanks!

-Stephen Spalding

Comment: Sorry to ask this so late...can you please post the controller code and any other so that it's a complete working example? Thanks so much.