# Spring ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider issue - Getting Supplied password was invalid

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, spring-ldap

Please take a look on configuration as shown below:

```
 ldap.urls=ldap://***.***.local:8389
    ldap.base.dn=dc=test,dc=com
    ldap.user.dn.pattern=(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0})(memberof=CN=Group Name,OU=***,OU=****,DC=test,DC=com))
```

## WebSecurityConfig.java

```
 @Configuration
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

        @Value("${ldap.url}")
        private String ldapUrl;

        @Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
        private String ldapDomain;

        @Value("${ldap.user.dn.pattern}")
        private String ldapUserDnPattern;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
                    this.ldapDomain, this.ldapUrl);

            adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
            adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

            // Checks with the Distinguished Name pattern provided
            if (this.ldapUserDnPattern != null && this.ldapUserDnPattern.trim().length() > 0) {
                adProvider.setSearchFilter(this.ldapUserDnPattern);
            }

            auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);

        }

    }
```

Can someone please tell me how to specify the userDn and password while configuring using ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070619/6572971 might help you.

Comment: Actually i also followed the same configuration even getting "Supplied password was invalid". I have setting up the userDN using pattern using setSearchFilter as shown above. Can you please help me out from this error. Thanks @Alien

Comment: your missing property ldap.base.dn=test.com.

Comment: Where i am missing, Can you please help on this. Thanks @TomB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define ldap.domain=test.com in your properties.

```
 @Configuration
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

        @Value("${ldap.url}")
        private String ldapUrl;

        @Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
        private String ldapBaseDN;

        @Value("${ldap.domain}")
        private String ldapDomain;

        @Value("${ldap.user.dn.pattern}")
        private String ldapUserDnPattern;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
                    this.ldapDomain, this.ldapUrl, this.ldapBaseDN);

            adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
            adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

            // Checks with the Distinguished Name pattern provided
            if (this.ldapUserDnPattern != null && this.ldapUserDnPattern.trim().length() > 0) {
                adProvider.setSearchFilter(this.ldapUserDnPattern);
            }

            auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Is ldap.domain and ldap.base.dn both are different? if different then what is the value need to be passed for ldap.domain ? thanks. @TomB

Comment: ldap.domain=test.com

Comment: ldap.base.dn=dc=test,dc=com

Comment: ldap.domain is needed, because it is appended to the login name. Login as "user" queires AD for "user@domain". This is one of the differeneces between AD and LDAP implementations in the spring adapters.

Comment: I am appending domain to the username like username@test.com while testing.Even getting the same.let me try with above config. thanks @TomB

Comment: Maybe leave away (memberof=CN=Group Name,OU=***,OU=****,DC=test,DC=com) at first and add it later on when you confirmed the rest to be working ok.

Comment: If i leave (memberof=CN=Group Name,OU=***,OU=****,DC=test,DC=com) this then AD how knows the group name. can you please explain me as i am new to this. Thanks @TomB.

Comment: Without this all users may be allowed to log in. Test this is working ok at first. Your restriction only allows user from the specified group to log in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178862/discussion-between-rajeswari-reddy-and-tomb).

Comment: Getting " ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point 
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied  [DEBUG] 2018-08-28 12:08:33.070 [http-nio-36454-exec-3] AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'POST /error' doesn't match 'GET /** 
  while testing from SOAP. and please find some of logs here. Thanks. @TomB